# Code Igniter Cannot access page via direct link

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I am creating a project with Code Igniter as a back end framework and Bootstrap 3 as a front end framework.

I'm having an issue with accessing my pages via directly calling the controller followed by the method.

For example my controller is site.php and the method is home.

Here is what is looks like.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home(){
        $data["title"] ="SmartAgent";

        $this->load->view("site_header");
        $this->load->view("content_home", $data);
        $this->load->view("site_footer");
    }
```

As I understand the method index basically sets the method home as the index page.

When I type the web address in my url such as:

```
examplesite.co.uk
```

The controller correctly loads my view for the home method, which is content_home.php and the site loads the homepage along with the title fine.

However if I type:

```
examplesite.co.uk/site/home
```

This does not work! And I do not know why, this is further causing me issues such as URL's not working etc etc. However base url is set, and I can load CSS, JS, and image files fine. Also I have enabled helpers, routes and all else.

The above url works to load another project I was working on. So is why I know I'm missing something.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Please put an example of your routes `application/config/routes.php`

Comment: Do you have .htaccess to remove index.php from the URL?

Comment: Most likely you need htaccess, and set your config/routes.php and config/config.php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207257/url-not-working-with-browser-other-than-chrome-htaccess-file-error/28207896#28207896

Comment: Hi there thank you for you reply, it was indeed the htaccess file, much appreciated @mustang83

Comment: Hi there @GopakumarGopalan I do there was a small issue which I later found please see my answer below, and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter routing is done relative to the `index.php`.

So your link should be `examplesite.co.uk/index.php/site/home`.

If that is the issue, then you need an .htaccess file, and in it write

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

(If I am not mistaken, writing from my phone)

Then, you will remove index.php from your site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I type my site as mentioned above: examplesite.co.uk/index.php/site/home this works and the other methods such as members also works i.e "index.php/site/members" but i didn't quite understand the htaccess file thingy, what will this do, and how come I didn't need to do this with another project, thank you in advance.

Comment: .htaccess is a web-configuration file for Apache web servers. I could try to guess that before someone reconfigured the project for you, or you didn't use an Apache environment. All you do is create a .htaccess file (that's right, it starts with a dot) and inside the file put that text. That should re-route all your url and remove the index.php from them, so you would use the links as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With codeigniter, you need to set `$route[]`. This is in `application/config/routes.php`

Also check out the codeigniter documentation on this, its pretty good and will explain it all.

Comment: Hi there thank you for your reply, but as mentioned above I have done this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help and answers!

This was a silly mistake of mine and I wanted to let everyone know so that if anyone was to face this issue this may help. @Alexey answer above gave me a light bulb moment! So thank you.

Basically within the .htaccess mod rewrite file which can be downloaded from google. I forgot to change the directory for my server which is located at the top on line 4

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /yourfolderdirectoryhere/
```

If you are unsure or unclear please watch below tutorial which helped me.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dynPx1B0jis
```