# url not working with browser other than chrome, htaccess file error

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, firefox

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|css|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have written this .htaccess file when I access `localhost/myProject/home` in Chrome this works fine but in other browsers it show page not found error

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need `Options +FollowSymLinks`. And for more htaccess for codeigniter click on link and download zip At David Connelly's Website. They have about 5 different ones that you could try in zip, no doubt one of them will work. http://www.insiderclub.org/downloads

The one I use below works fine in all browsers for codeigniter. Make sure when you use this or any other htaccess, that you place your domain in base url at config/config.php and then remove the index.php from config/config.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Whats your routes.php say?

Comment: the thing is that when i tried to access it in firefox via localhost/project/index.php/home, it works fine. but not working while using localhost/project/home

Comment: i didn't made any changes to route.php files yet

Comment: Have you downloaded htacess zip and tried the ones. Did you remove the index.php from config.php file.

Comment: In your routes you need to set a default controller.  `$route['default_controller'] = 'folder/controller'; ` and then you may add other routes.